# Copying Xth sheet from N Excel workbooks into a new workbook-which language to use?

Tags: c#, java, ruby, excel, groovy

I understand that I can use VBA but

- I've found a way to get a sheet by name but not by location  (5th sheet in workbook) or wildcard of name (sheet always named Results-*)
- I'd rather the user didn't have to install Excel on his machine in order to run this.

I'd appreciate suggestions as to language/libraries in which this is the easiest to accomplish, from the following list:

- Java
- C#
- Groovy
- Ruby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Java the [getSheet(int)](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/Workbook.html#getSheet%28int%29) method in the [JExcelApi](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) does this.

Answer (score 1):

In ruby with the [roo](http://roo.rubyforge.org/) gem you can

```
sheet = Excel.new('path/to/file').sheets[int]
```

I doesn't require Excel to be installed, but I'm not sure if it does sheet name pattern matching.

Comment: if it can get the sheet by number it'll be quite enough for me. Thanks a lot!!